# Beamer display `\pause` only temporarly

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am using a bunch of pause statements on a single slide in order to make the slide slowly build up. How do I make a single item appear and then disappear using the Beamer `\pause` option? So basically smth. along the lines of:

---

- Item 1

---

---

- Item 1
- Item 2

---

---

- Item 1

---

---

- Item 1
- Item 3

---

Comment: Welcome :) // Please provide code via the Edit button of what you tried so far. Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: Read the chapter 9 of the Beamer manual "Creating overlays that start with "The pause command offers an easy, **but not very flexible** way of creating frames ..."

Comment: @MS-SPO Hello, thanks. :) The only thing that works / that I tried is "duplicating" modified versions slides and not using `\pause` at all. I have no idea how I would use `\pause` for that. @Fran Thanks, I was already suspecting that.

Comment: @Fabian Modify duplicates of frames is the hard way. Again: read (all) the chapter 9. For instance, you can change simply the first `\item` to `\item<1-2,4>` to make four slides of the list where the first item is always showed except in the slide 3, but there are more option for lists or any text fragment. See for instance  this [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642804/tcolorbox-and-pause). Again, read (all) the chapter 9.