# tcolorbox and pause

Tags: tcolorbox, pause

I have problems using `\pause` inside a `tcolorbox` with the option `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`. Doing so results in the order of uncovering to be messed up. For instance, when using an `itemize` inside a `tcolorbox`, the box containing the items gets revealed only at the very end.

Is there a way to fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item A first item.\pause
                \item A second item.\pause
            \end{itemize}
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Another box \pause with a pause.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `\uncover` the covered.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            The pause \uncover<2>{does not work the way it should.}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

In response to the comment asking additionally for uncover  list items:

Although `\pause` was intended to work inside environments, from the manual: "*However, taking this to extremes and using \pause deeply within a nested environment may not have the desired result.*"  So, better think on `\pause` as just a "stop reading"  that could avoid read the end of the environments in the first slide, and remember that are several others commands for slide overlays. To uncover sequentially items of a list, you can:

```
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> A first item.
            \item<2-> A second item.
        \end{itemize}
```

Or...

```
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+-> A first item.
        \item<+-> A second item.
    \end{itemize}
```

Or simpler:

```
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item A first item.
            \item A second item.
        \end{itemize}
```

About the messed aspect of commands with arguments ... "*c'est la vie*" `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: This works great in this example, but gets really nested and messy once you want to use many pauses in a single slide. Also, I do not think that it works well with lists, does it? I updated my question to fit my need.

Answer (score 2):

One way is use `visible`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \begin{itemize}[<+->]
                \item A first item. 
                \item A second item.\ 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \visible<3->{Another box} 
            \visible<4>{with a pause}.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]